# Texture wont change after duplication

Tags: materials

I've got following problem:
I have an object in my blendfile which already has a face, differing by material.
When I now press 'P' to seperate and then 'by material' it becomes an independant object, but I can't change the material of it.
Is there a way to do it or do I have to create a new plane ?

Comment: the material should indeed be editable via the material menue (remove, asign, etc.). If you could upload a file maby there is a problem to detect elsewere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try:

1) Select the new object, and remove the old material, then add a new material. This should disconnect the material of the new object from the old one.

2) Select the old object and go to **Object > Apply > Make duplicates real**. This will make the duplicates connected to the object (in case somehow the object is a duplicate) a real object.

3) Select the new object, and go to **Object > Users > Make single user-Object & Data & Materials & tex**.

If one of these three things do not fix the problem, I don't know what can.

Comment: Thank you! that helped a lot. The first worked